# Passing MySQL client config to "rails db"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, config, my.cnf

I'm wondering how to pass MySQL client config to the "rails db" command, ie config options that would normally be specified on the "mysql" command line as flags or in my.cnf.

Specifically:

- I want to set a flag, `sigint-ignore` (because accidental ctrl-c exits are all too easy)
- I want to set the DB password from an env variable ("rails db" doesn't seem to look at database.yml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rails db` - alias to [`rails dbconsole`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-dbconsole) - uses the config in `config/database.yml` and opens the appropriate command line interface.

For connecting to `mysql` databases, [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) is specified as the adapter in `config/database.yml` with `adapter: mysql2`.

`mysql2 adapter` provides for reading from a custom mysql configuration file with the `:default_file` and `:default_group` parameters; see https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#reading-a-mysql-config-file

#### `sigint-ignore` can be specified as follows:

In `config/database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: example_dev
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  default_file: /Users/mahemoff/.my.cnf
  default_group: client
```

In `/Users/mahemoff/.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
sigint-ignore
```

#### Setting DB password

> "rails db" doesn't seem to look at database.yml)

`rails db` does use the password set in `database.yml`.

Comment: sigint-ignore worked. The password still doesn't work for me. Possibly because my database.yml just includes code references, as the config is based on Figaro. It's not the actual password specified there.